# Is it possible to execute "hg pull rebase" with IntelliJ IDEA 12+

Tags: mercurial, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 13 EAP with h4idea default Mercurial plugin.

I was trying to figure out a way to do `hg pull --rebase` equivalent from the IDE.

In my workflow it is very common to commit something on my local repo and then before I do a `hg push` I have to pull the recent changes from other team members and rebase them with my latest commit.

Is this possible or I have to use terminal or create an External Task?

Answer (score 2):

1) Unsafe, using alias in hgrc:

```
[extensions]
rebase =

[alias]
pull = pull --rebase
```

Just make sure you aware of consequences of ([highly unrecommended](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#alias)) default command override and behavior of rebase in all [scenarios](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RebaseExtension).

2) Safe, editing "External Tools" in IDEA's settings, creating "hg rebase" which will be available on RightClick and under Tools menu (not to mention hotkeys via Settings/Keymap).